# palindrome in python using while and if

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop, repeat, palindrome

I am trying to do a palindrome checker code in python, but instead of printing `‘its not a palindrome’` for a wrong answer I want the answer to be `’sorry try again’`

I tried to use a `while` loop but when I run it it prints the answer infinitely.

```
def palindrome_check(a):
    b = 3
    while b%2 != 0:
        if a == a[::-1] :
            print('its a palindrome')
            b = 2
        else :
            print('sorry try again ')
            b = 1
    return a
palindrome_check( a = str(input('enter a valid string: ')))
```

Comment: Why do you set `b` to `1`? If you do, and run `1 % 2 != 0` it is obvious that the condition is true and you never set `b` again. The loop will not halt then.

Comment: Your input is not a part of the loop. You get input once and then keep checking the same value every time

Comment: You could use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) and [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#all) to test for palindrome using:   `def checkPal(t:str)->bool:
    return False if (t == None or not t) else all(a==b for a,b in zip(t,t[::-1]))` - essentially comparing a paring of the last to the first character - you can optimize by only comparing towards half of the stringaswell, but thats even uglier when pasted in comment ;)